# How can i clear multiple text boxes when backspace is pressed?

Tags: c#

Right now I am using this code which is clearing textboxes simultaneously i want to do it separately

```
private void metroTile13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtUser.Text = txtUser.Text.Remove(txtUser.Text.Length - 1, 1);
            txtPass.Text = txtPass.Text.Remove(txtUser.Text.Length - 1, 1);
        }
```

Comment: Add to all text box a key press event, If key press is backspace Do your logic.

Comment: Then do it seperately? I don't see an actual question to be honest

Comment: Knowing how to do this would be interesting, but if an application did that because I pressed backspace, I would be surprised and annoyed. Where have you come across a GUI that did that? Backspace should always be one character at a time.

Comment: @Novaterata Knowing would not be interesting, just a keydown/keypressed event that executes a method, nothing special. But yes indeed it would be a nuisance if a program would do that :)

Comment: @EpicKip I was being diplomatic

Comment: Why are people even answering? there is no actual question there -_- the title is a different "question" than the body is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
txtUser.KeyPress += ClearTextboxes;
txtPass.KeyPress += ClearTextboxes;

private void ClearTextboxes(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back) 
    {
        (TextBox)sender.Text = string.Empty();
    }
}
```